# Angular 6 - Toggle Class on clicked items and toggle Class off other items

Tags: angular, ng-class

I have an Angular loop that's returning a a list of items from my database. Inside each of those items is an array (which is where the second `*ngFor` loop is.)

The second loop (`*ngFor="let option of item.options`) will have four results. When I click on the `<li>` with a class of question I want to add a class to highlight it. However, if I click on another `<li>` (for example, option 3 out of the 4), I would like to add a class to that one, but remove it from the first clicked `<li>`.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div>{{ item.question }}</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="question" *ngFor="let option of item.options">
        {{option}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It might be worth noting that I could have up to 15 items in the first loop `*ngFor="let item of items | async"`

Comment: Try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1prlfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is similar to an answer below whereby if I have more than one question (in the first ngFor loop), then a selected answer in question one will be removed when an answer for another question is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easy way is use a variable called e.g. "itemSelect" and use in *ngFor="..;let i=index", on click equal the variable to i and use [ngClass] or [className]. As you has two *ngFor you need an array of variables

```
<!--take acount the let i=index-->
<li *ngFor="let item of items | async;let i=index">
   ...
    <ul>
      <!--use itemSelect[i]-->
      <li [className]="j==itemSelect[i]?'question hightligth':'question'
          *ngFor="let option of item.options;let j=index" 
           (click)="itemSelect[i]=j">
            {{option}}
      </li>
    </ul>
<li>
```

Dont forget declare in your ts

```
itemSelect:number[]=[]
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. This only highlights all four answers in question whilst clicking answer 1. Clicking answers on any of the other questions, nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, so this does work, but there's a couple of errors in the code. First there needs to be a second `ul` before the nested `li`. Secondly, instead of `i==itemSelect[i]` it needs to be `j==itemSelect[i]`. Also, the last `li` wasn't closed correctly. If you're able to update your answer (just for the reference of other users, I'll mark it as the answer! - Thanks Eliseo, much appreciated!

Comment: @Que, thanks for the advise, and my apologies by my error code (just corrected)

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by updating your html as follows

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div>{{ item.question }}</div>
    <ul>
    <li class="question"
        [class.active]="i == parentIndex && j == childIndex"
        (click)="setClickedRow(i, j)"
        *ngFor="let option of item.options; let j = index">
        {{ option }}
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Finally you need to update your ts file as follows

```
parentIndex : Number;
childIndex : Number;

setClickedRow(i,j){
 this.parentIndex=i;
 this.childIndex = j;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm afraid this doesn't work either. It works if I have one question with four possible answers. But the first ngFor loop is looping through up to 13 questions. In your example, clicking an answer in question 2 will remove the class that was added to an answer in question 1, and so on for all other questions